# Glassfish 4.1.2 error

Tags: java, glassfish

I downloaded and unzipped glassfish from glassfish-4.1.2.zip

After that I installed java jdk and have the ff path in my c directory program files:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
```

I then deployed the war file from my project.  I also updated the ff files in glassfish:

```
asenv.bat, added set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
asenv.conf, added AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

Restarted glassfish and launch the project but getting the error below:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

Am I missing some configuration or need to change something?

EDIT: I'm using windows 10 but not sure if OS has any effect on glassfish

Answer (score 0):

Probably you also need to change domain.xml (java-home inside java-config).
Setting JAVA_HOME system environment variable is also good practice, you never know what and when is going to use it.